# How make a bootable ISO for my UEFI application bare bones?

Tags: boot, virtualbox, uefi, iso-image

Well, I maked a rust UEFI application and run it on the efi shell of virtualbox ( development of my application is on ubuntu 20.04 and tests are hosted on virtualbox installed on windows 10 session ).

To do this, I make an ISO file like :

```
xorriso -as mkisofs -R -J -o myiso.iso /some/directories/BOOTX64.EFI /some/others/directories/myapp.elf
```

When Im on virtualbox, I switch to FS0 file system and I can see my 2 executables : ( **BOOTX64.EFI** and **myapp.elf** ). The **BOOTX64.EFI** is launched by command line, work and return some information like the gop protocol framebuffer localisation and some other stuff. I also use the EFI file system to load and use **myapp.elf** and for this part of program, it doesn't give information about **myapp.elf** file or I can't read it. ( no error, no warning, I'm almost sure my code in the EFI application is correct but for example, the file_info protocol return 0 ( size or file_size )).

I think the problem is my ISO file, isn't a true bootable file format. For example, after switched FS0 file system and list the content on the EFI shell, all executables information like date or hour are at 0. ( only file size is returned correctly ).

I don't wanna use application like grub or isolinux because the goal of my project is to learn to make that. ^^

If someone can explain step by step the procedure to make a bootable .ISO of UEFI application bare bones with some others executables included in the .ISO, will be really appreciated.

*Hopefully that's the problem...*

Comment: See if this thread helps. https://superuser.com/questions/1353671/run-efi-files-scripts-from-boot-virtual-media-iso/1357260#1357260  Create a FAT image with \EFI\Boot file structure and place your bootx64.efi at \Boot and then write that entire FAT image as bootfile in xorriso (not just .efi) to create your bootable ISO.

Comment: I suggest first see if you can boot into bootx64.efi from the ISO. Then figure out how the two interface, which I have no much idea about.

Comment: Hmm ok, for make a FAT image of my **bootx64.efi** ( with directories structure ) + **myapp.elf**, I need to make : 1) a little FAT partition, 2) in this partition, I copy my project executable files/structure in, 3) generate an image of my project in the FAT partition, 4) Make the .ISO with the FAT.img and some bootable options. Im right?

Comment: I can not comment about your project files and how they are organized. The bootloader bootx64.efi should be inside FAT image at \EFI\boot and probably the elf if bootloader is calling it. But again how to call is I guess what you need to figure out. Hence I suggest first see if it runs bootx64.efi or not and then look for the next interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you reopened the question on superuser I decided to give it a go on my own side.

The culprit is that you create an ISO without partitioning the ISO as GPT and without marking any partition as ESP (EFI System Partition). You are thus left with an ISO that is not recognized by the basic utilities shipped with UEFI including the filesystem drivers.

What you need to do is to make an ESP on your system and then make an ISO out of that ESP. Follow these steps:

1. Create a disk.img full of zeroes.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=512 count=93750
```

2. Partition that raw zeroed image with GPT and create a ESP partition on it(type in order o, y, n, default, default, default, ef00, w, y). See the image for more details on the steps of the gdisk command.

```
gdisk disk.img
```

[image: gdisk-example]

3. Setup a loopback device to mount the disk.img. The disk.img file here is a raw hard-disk image. It isn't in any special format like a .iso format. It means that nor the Linux archiver nor the Linux mount utility will recognize it. You need to use losetup to setup a loopback device that will make this raw disk image into an actual fake hard-disk device that the mount utility can then mount easily. The offset in the command specifies where the partition starts. You can use `fdisk -lu disk.img` to find out where this partition starts. The offset given here is the right one for the steps I've mentionned above so it should work without problem.

```
sudo losetup --offset 1048576 --sizelimit 46934528 /dev/loop5 disk.img
```

4. Create a FAT32 filesystem on the loopback device. Basically, you are creating a full filesystem on the ESP partition.

```
sudo mkdosfs -F 32 /dev/loop5
```

5. Mount the filesystem on /mnt.

```
sudo mount /dev/loop5 /mnt
```

6. Copy the efi app to the mount point.

```
sudo cp path/to/boot.efi /mnt
```

7. Copy the kernel to the mount point.

```
sudo cp path/to/kernel.elf /mnt
```

8. Make an ISO file out of the whole mount point.

```
sudo mkisofs -o disk.iso /mnt
```

9. Give permission to all users on the ISO.

```
sudo chmod a+rwx disk.iso
```

10. Attach the ISO file to the virtual box cd-rom then boot the machine. You should now have your efi app in the shell along with the kernel. You should be able to boot the kernel now.

Also, feel free to put the last few commands in a script and run it directly like such:

```
sudo cp path/to/boot.efi /mnt
sudo cp path/to/kernel.elf /mnt
sudo mkisofs -o disk.iso /mnt
sudo chmod a+rwx disk.iso
```

You don't need to rerun the first few commands because, once the filesystem is mounted, you just need to copy new compiled files onto the mount point and make a new ISO file out of it. Maybe you have to rerun the first commands when you reboot I haven't tested.

Also, with this method, you don't need to setup virtual box anymore. Just set it up once to use the disk.iso file and it will always use the same file even if you modify it.

One last thing is that /dev/loop5 may be busy. Maybe try another higher loopback device if it is the case or try `sudo umount /dev/loop5`.

Comment: Quality response, thank for your explanation!

Comment: However, the problem is still present. ( virtualbox ) and I can't boot on QEMU either. If I use some command like `isoinfo -d -i disk.iso` or `file disk.iso` the **disk.iso** isn't considered bootable.  On virtualbox, I can start  `EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` present in the **disk.iso** with efi shell command line but always the same problem.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the bootloader code maybe share some excerpt. I may be able to help further.

Comment: I tested my method and I can actually boot my own kernel on virtual box.

Comment: If I make a filesystem image : `dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/file.img bs=512 count=93750 \ mformat -i /path/file.img -f 1440 :: \ mmd -i /path/file.img ::/EFI \ mmd -i /path/file.img ::/EFI/BOOT \ mcopy -i /path/file.img /path/of/my/bootx64.efi ::/EFI/BOOT \ mcopy -i /path/file.img /path/of/my/app.elf ::` and use it on **Qemu** or **virtualbox** ( **without use xorriso or mkisofs** ), it work and date and hour of file and directories on efi shell ( in the image ) are returned correctly. ( victory! ). But efi file system for load my .elf file still does't work. I will continue to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI boot is purely filesystem-based - unlike BIOS's, which makes use of boot sectors that are not part of a filesystem.

Place a file called `bootx64.efi` in a directory called `EFI\boot`. That's it. UEFI will find and boot it.

Note that for different system architectures, the filename will be different.

Comment: I have already tried this in my .ISO file, it looks like this:

`-> EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
 -> myapp.elf `

and when I run the command line, to execute EFI application, it's same result like I have describd in my first post. ( with or without directories ).